# Excel - need to find all cells in column B where the numbers are in sequential order

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Here is what I have

```
A                                     B         C


ICING VEMAG FILLER                    200034    200034  
RSD BULK                              200035    200035  
RSD TRAY                              200036    200036
```

So I need column B to have each row here say the max value which would be 200036 in that range

So the result should be

```
A                                      B        C 


ICING VEMAG FILLER                     200036   200034  
RSD BULK                               200036   200035  
RSD TRAY                               200036   200036
```

Comment: Welcome to SU.  We'll need a little more information/work from you... What have you tried already? What were the results of those tries? A simple ["If" statement](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if.php) should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some conflict between your title, text and example. Perhaps you mean "need to find the largest value in column C and use that in column B". If so, use the =MAX() formula for each cell in column B? So in this case:

```
=max(C$1:C$3)
```